# Is string builder the right choice?

Tags: c#, string, serial-port

So from what I understand of a `string` vs `StringBuilder` is that string builder will actually modify the instance of itself while string will just make a new one. So if I understand this correctly then by using the string method for a constantly changing variable I could basically be eventually using all the memory until the computer needs to dump it to make room.

What I am doing is using an event handler to monitor serial communication. I will take in the data and parse it out plus display it in a text box. The event handler uses string to accomplish this currently. In concern for better programming and not using up all the memory when I don't need to I am trying to clean up my code.

I started to code with string builder and begun to get the build error that `StringBuilder` does not contain a .contains method.

Basically I am curious if i should leave it alone? Should I approach this differently? and do I have the right understanding in that `string` will inevitably run me out of memory?

```
private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;

    string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
    rx.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + indata);
    string dataCheck = indata.ToUpper();
    if (dataCheck.Contains("CONNECT") || indata.Contains("CONNECTED"))
    {
        cState.Text = "Connected";
        connectLink();
    }
    if (dataCheck.Contains("NO CARRIER"))
    {
        cState.Text = "Disconnected";
        disconnect();
    }
    dataCheck = null;
}
```

Comment: for questions similar to this one, [codereview.se] is also a good place to look... by the way, you can get rid of the `dataCheck = null;` assignment since it will have no measurable effect on memory. The garbage collector will collect `dataCheck` eventually, regardless of whether you assign null or not.

Comment: Right now, your code is so drastically broken that the question is irrelevant.  ReadExisting() will never give you a string like "CONNECT" in the Real World.  You'll only get that when you debug your code.  At best you'll get "CO" when you run your code without a debugger.

Comment: The `|| indata.Contains("CONNECTED")` is not needed because searching for "CONNECT" will cover this case.  Plus, you most likely meant to search `dataCheck`.

Comment: Just for the sake of clarity for anyone else that might be reading this, Hans brings up a point that I should have been clear on. The data revived are status lines spit out by a specific device. So it sends out those specific terms. So far this is working but I was concerned about memory usage over time.

Richard, Thanks for teaching me that. I was under the impression that the contains function was exact. I did not realize that I could get away with only checking for connect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are incorrect; using String will not (in general) cause you to run out of memory.

If you're doing lots of concatenation, using string is less efficient, since it needs to build a new string and throw away the old string every time you concatenate.
In such scenarios, you should use a StringBuilder to build the string, then call `ToString()` whenever you want to display it.

Your code does not contain any concatenation, so using StringBuilder wouldn't do any good.

Comment: *"You are incorrect; using String will not cause you to run out of memory.*" Sure it can (theoretically), though I can't say if it is a problem in this situation.  I once had to fix an OOM situation caused by the allocation of many large strings, which in turn fragmented the LOH and eventually resulted in an OOM exception.